# VS Team Services and website portal, in lieu of SharePoint

Tags: azure-devops

VSTS cannot link to sharepoint for a portal.  The only option is a web site.  Is there any documentation as to the requirements for the website?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any requirement for website since TFS/VSTS does not perform any integration with the website. When you click "Show Project Portal..." from "VS\Team", it just open the website URL from browser. So you just need to make sure the website linked can be accessed by your team members.

Comment: hmmm - so if i created a sharepoint site using the development template, that might work.  It won't be integrated into VSTS, but I'll have the wiki, discussions, and document storage capability.

Comment: @PhilBoyd Yes. But before do this, you can try to add some other website to see if the it can be linked successfully. There was an issue that the website cannot be linked for some VSTS account. Refer to this link for details: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fd5e71c3-6185-41cd-8139-b9b858fff7f0/tf205029-no-catalog-resource-type-exists-with-the-following-identifier?forum=TFService

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, VSTS version control integration can offer a lot.

You can customize the welcome page and from there link Markdown files in version control: Markdown is nicely rendered.